# add an item into sublist as value inside a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I suppose this could be easy, but I could not find how to do it. If I have a dictionary d:
`d = {1: [4,3], 5:[6,7,8]}`

How can I add another value (ex. 2) to the sublist [4, 3], to obtain this:
`d = {1: [4,3,2], 5:[6,7,8]}`

Comment: nothing magic here. 1) access the list 2) append

Comment: @user3100115 thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple.

```
d = {1: [4,3], 5: [6,7,8]}
d[1].append(2)
```